# How to create a simple GUI lib?

Tags: user-interface, framebuffer

I need to create a simple gui toolkit based on only a raw framebuffer.
Are there any examples or papers describing such a thing?

Obviously I could implement X but I think that's a little beyond the scope :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this for a Linux framebuffer? [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) is a graphics library worth looking at. It is a mature open source project, which makes it a good project to study and learn from. The documentation is also pretty good. Like many GUI toolkits it has a large API set, but you don't have to use all of it and can focus on just what you are interested. Developing a GUI toolkit can be a complex task.

Comment: No, it's for a custom microprocessor.  Although SDL probably had to deal with many of the same issues I will have to address.

Answer (score 0):

The best examples would be other GUI libraries out there.

Take a look at X, GTK, Microsoft's WPF and WinForms.

Also, you might want to look at other UI technologies, like HTML and CSS.

On the more minimal side, there's things like Curses and Mono's [gui.cs](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoCurses#gui.cs).

Figure out how things are done, and how they could do better, and create a design. Then **throw it away** and create a *new* design, because creating a good design requires iteration.

Comment: Those are very large and complicated gui toolkits.
I am however intrigued about a gui based on SVG.  Sort of like the old postscript interfaces.

Comment: They're only large because they have a lot of stuff. You can look at them and see some of the overarching design principles employed (Is it model-view-controller? Is everything conceptually a handle? Does it manage layout or do you?) without having to go in too deep.

A GUI based on SVG would be interesting. A full SVG renderer might be a bit difficult to write, but using SVG would help abstract the GUI itself from the framework.